# How do you extract the commits of a single file into a fresh git tree?

Tags: git, refactoring

I'm splitting out a library from an existing source tree so the library can be maintained separately.

How do you extract all the commits for one file and import them into another tree, but without all the .git/objects clutter from the original tree?

I was thinking something like this:

```bash
cd /new/tree
git init

cd /original/tree
git show --reverse  815f0f..HEAD -- lib/PDL/Opt/Simplex/Simple.pm | \
    (cd /new/tree ; git am)
```

but it gives errors and won't import.

I also thought of just branching, deleting everything, and then fetching the pruned branch into a new tree---but (I think) that would import all the other tree's commit data in .git/objects that would be orphaned in the new tree.

Is there a "proper" way to do this cleanly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from https://github.com/PDLPorters/devops/blob/master/NOTES.md#how-to-split-history:

### How to split history

Make sure `git-subtree` is installed and works (if not, get from
https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh and place
with `+x` in `/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-subtree`)

```bash
# example for pdla-io-hdf
KITCHENSINKREPO=$HOME/pdla
KITCHENSINKDIR=IO/HDF
SPLITOUTREPO=$HOME/pdla-io-hdf
SPLITBRANCH=splitout
MASTER=master
pushd $KITCHENSINKREPO
git subtree split -P $KITCHENSINKDIR -b $SPLITBRANCH
git push $SPLITOUTREPO $SPLITBRANCH:$SPLITBRANCH
git branch -D $SPLITBRANCH
cd $SPLITOUTREPO
git checkout $MASTER
git reset --hard $SPLITBRANCH
git branch -d $SPLITBRANCH
git push origin
popd
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked.  I'm open to other answers, too, if you have a better way:

```bash
git format-patch --stdout 815f0f..HEAD -- lib/PDL/Opt/Simplex/Simple.pm | \
    (cd ../perl-PDL-Opt-Simplex-Simple/ ; git am)
```

Comment: I'd probably fuss about with the new `git filter-repo` for a while, but your method should be fine for a non-branching series of commits. (A big chunk of my fussing-about would just be learning to drive the Python code in it :-) )

Comment: That said, I'm not sure why you care about any leftover commit data. Just do the operation and then run the checklist from `git filter-branch`, or clone the clone to a third fresh clone, or some such.